# Restructuring database and multiple views for model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a system where a user can input data into various forms and generate a custom document.  When I set everything up, because each form has unique data, I create a Model/Controller for each type of document e.g. BriefDocument, InvoiceDocument etc.

I soon discovered that this became very messy, way too many Models and Controllers.  It also took quite a long time to create a new document type.  As such, I have rearranged my database.

I now have a Document model and a DocumentData model.  A Document can have many Document Data.  I envision something like this

```
Document
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| id | name          | description     | 
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 1  | BriefDocument | Something       |    
+----+---------------+-----------------+

DocumentData
+----+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
| id | key          | value           | documentId   |
+----+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 1  | whatData     | inputted data   | 1            |  
+----+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 2  | whoData      | inputted data   | 1            |  
+----+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 3  | whyData      | inputted data   | 1            |  
+----+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 4  | howData      | inputted data   | 1            |  
+----+--------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Doing this should allow me to create any type of Document using just these two models.  My first problem is this, I have set up the routes as follows

```
Route::model('projects.document', 'Document');
Route::resource('projects.document', 'DocumentController', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
```

On a page I have a dropdown where the user can select the type of document they create.  The dropdown has things like this

```
<li>{!! link_to_route('projects.document.create', 'Brief Document', array($project->id, 'Brief Document')) !!}</li>
```

So this will call the create function within my DocumentController

```
public function create(Project $project, $name)
{
    $briefDocument = Document::where('projectId', '=', $project->id)
        ->where('name', '=', $name)
        ->first();
}
```

What I am trying to do in this function is first determine whether the same Document has already been created for this Project, because a Project can only have many documents, but no repeat documents.

If I do this however, I get

```
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController::create()
```

But am I not passing it arguement 2 within the link_to_route?  From what I can see, this is passing my Project instance, as well as the string Briefing Document.

Why would I be getting this error?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
If I explicitly set the route it works e.g.

```
Route::model('projects.document', 'Document');
Route::get('projects/{projects}/document/{name}', array('as' => 'projects.document.create', 'uses' => 'DocumentController@create'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error, because you do not pass `$name` variable to the `create()` action.

Maybe the problem is in `create()` itself. This method is a part of RESTful controller and looks like it was designed to accept only `Request` object, so try this:

```
<li>{!! link_to_route('projects.document.create', 'Brief Document', ['project_id' => $project->id, 'name' => Brief Document')) !!}</li>
```

And `create()` action:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('project_id');
    $name = $request->get('name');

    $briefDocument = Document::where('projectId', '=', $project->id)
        ->where('name', '=', $name)
        ->first();
}
```

Comment: Am I not doing that in my link_to_route though?  Where should I pass it?  Thanks

Comment: You're passing `$project->id`, but action expecting `$project` object. Try to pass an object or change `Project $project` to `$id`.

Comment: Still complains about parameter 2

Comment: Can you show HTML code generated by `link_to_route` please.

Comment: <a href="http://localhost:8000/projects/1/document/create?Brief%20Document">Brief Document</a>

Comment: Made an update to OP - works if I set the route manually, but is there not a way to do it the way I had it before?

Comment: I've updated my post. It seems the problem is in `create()` itself, because it's a part of RESTful controller (and resource route). You can try to change name or you could try to use code from my answer, but you said you've already made it work.